# Remove Dropbox folder from computer

Tags: dropbox

I have created a Dropbox account, downloaded the software, setup the folder, and created symbolic links to monitor folders. The first problem was that the symbolic links that I thought I had set up for Documents, Videos, Music, etc. were actually for My Documents, My Music, My Videos, My etc.

I've uninstalled the dropbox software and deleted the Dropbox folder, the My Videos, My Music, My Documents, etc. leaving the Videos, Music, Documents, etc. folders that are inherent to the Windows 7 OS.

Now the problem I have is that the Dropbox folder and the My [folder name] folders keep coming back and have to be deleted.

Does anyone know how I can permanently delete them without having them come back? Keep in mind the Dropbox software is no longer on the computer so it isn't being recreated b/c of that.

Comment: If dropbox is not longer on the computer why is the dropbox folder coming back??
Why do you want to get rid of the standard windows library folders?

Comment: Did you delete the bad folders on your Dropbox account ?

Comment: Did you uninstall dropbox from your computer???

Comment: Yes the bad folders have been deleted from the dropbox account, and I have uninstalled the dropbox client from my computer so even if i had not deleted the folders they should not be coming from the dropbox account.

Comment: I want to get rid of the "standard windows library folders" because by creating the sym links two sets of the standard windows library folders. One set is just Documents, Videos, Music. The other set is My Documents, My Videos, and My Music. My suspcion is that there may be a program, or windows itself that is recreating the dropbox folder, and these folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a backup of the directories you symlinked. Once that is done, delete the directories, and the symlink should be removed.

So lets make this an example:

Backup C:\Users\Simon\Video

Then once its been backed up, delete the folder. Use command prompt for this.

Cd to the folder, ex:

```
$ cd C:\Users\Simon
```

then

```
$ rmdir Videos
```

Restore the folder once its done. This should stop it.

Comment: That seems to have worked, although, I found that one folder it was linked to somehow was actually directly on the C:\ so I deleted it using the cmd prompt. It seems that I did the orignal symlinks backwards and managed to accidentally create a folder for one of the symlinks.