# How can I remove the Dropbox folder from This PC on Win10

Tags: windows-10

I have removed Dropbox a while ago.  But I had two Dropbox folders left on File Explorer which defaults to **This PC**

One was a shortcut and I could remove it.  The other one is not so simple

- Keyboard <kbd>Del</kbd> has no effect
- Right Click menu does not have a `Delete` or `Remove Shortcut` options
- It has `Open` and `Pin to` Options and `Properties` which is blank.
- I have rebooted several times

How can I remove it?

[Remove Dropbox folder from computer](https://superuser.com/questions/288712/remove-dropbox-folder-from-computer) is not a duplicate, because I can't delete it in the first place.

[image]

Comment: If Dropbox is truly uninstalled, try Unlocker 1.92 (Major Geeks) to delete the files and then the folder. Windows Defender will complain about Unlocker so you will need to whitelist it. I use it and would not be without it.   You might also try logging onto dropbox live if you can and remove the files there.'

Comment: When you click on that `dropbox` folder  where does it take you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an orphaned CLSID in the registry, most likely under:.

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\Namespace
```

Not sure of the value (and can't search right now, but it may be obvious. If, not, search for each value you find under:.

```
HKCR:\CLSID
```

and it should be evident somehow.

Comment: Was not this entry, but it led me to other orphaned entries - I deleted all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and for marking as `Answer`.